# How to read a directory from the runtime classpath?

Tags: java, classpath

My Java application needs to be able to find a `myconfig/` directory which will be bundled inside the same JAR:

```
myjar.jar/
    com/
        me/
            myproject/
                ConfigLoader.java --> looks for myconfig/ directory and its contents
    myconfig/
        conf-1.xml
        conf.properties
        ... etc.
```

How do I actually go about reading this `myconfig/` directory off the runtime classpath? I've done some research and it seems that the normal method of reading a **file** from the classpath doesn't work for **directories**:

```
InputStream stream = ConfigLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("myconfig");
```

So does anyone know how to read an entire directory from the runtime classpath (as opposed to a single file)? Thanks in advance!

Please note: It is not possible to load the files individually, `myconfig` is a directory with thousands of properties files inside it.

Comment: I'm trying to simplify the problem for the sake of explaining it. There is a library called `langdetect` hosted on google [here](http://code.google.com/p/language-detection/). The library ships with a `profiles` directory that it uses to load every single language properties file into the runtime classpath. At runtime you need to call a `DetectFactory.loadProfile(String)` method to initialize the `profiles/` directory. So this directory needs to be on the classpath. I can get this working when I pass it an abs file path, but ultimately need to package this inside the same JAR.

Comment: So, ultimately, I just need to pass `DetectFactory.loadProfiles` a String that points it to the `profiles` directory inside the same JAR. So whereas my example shows `myconfig` directory, its really `profiles`. Where it shows `ConfigLoader`, its really `DetectFactory`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` provided by Spring.

```
public class SpringResourceLoader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();

        // Ant-style path matching
        Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("/myconfig/**");

        for (Resource resource : resources) {
            InputStream is = resource.getInputStream();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't do anything fancy with the returned `Resource` but you get the picture.

Add this to your maven dependency (if using maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could call `ClassLoader.getResource()` to find a particular file in the directory (or the directory itself, if `getResource()` will return directories). `getResource()` returns a URL pointing to the result. You could then convert this URL into whatever form the other library requires.

Comment: The `getResource()` method does in fact return directories.

Answer (score 0):

The trick seems to be that the class loader can find directories in the classpath, while the class can not.

So this works

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("com/example/foo/myconfig");
```

while this does not

```
this.getClass().getResource("myconfig");
```

Answer (score -2):

```
String path = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("myproperties.properties").getPath();
```