# Read the contents of files in a specific package

Tags: java, inputstream, package

I'm surprised I couldn't find an answer to this question on stackoverflow, but please forgive me if this is a duplicate.

I have some text files sitting in a package in my web application. I know what the package is called, but I don't necessarily know what the files are called. I want to be able to read the contents of each of the text files in this package.

I know I could read the contents of individual files using `getClass().getResourceAsStream("filename.txt")`, but as I say I don't necessarily know the names of the files, just the package they reside in.

So, given a package name, how can I get the contents of all the files contained within that package?

Comment: You could check out this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12007322/1350762 You have to give the path to the files like `com/myapp/some/package/*`.

Comment: Worked a treat - @maba if you convert your comment to an answer I'm happy to accept it. Cheers.

Comment: I copied my own answer from the link into an answer on this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding my own answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12007322/1350762 as a community wiki.

You can use the `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` provided by Spring.

```
public class SpringResourceLoader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();

        // Ant-style path matching
        Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("/com/myapp/some/package/*");

        for (Resource resource : resources) {
            InputStream is = resource.getInputStream();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Add this to your maven dependency (if using maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```