# Read folder from jar using getResource() method

Tags: java, fonts, jar, classpath

Here is my code

```
/** Loads fonts for the L&F. */
private void loadFonts() {
    try {
        final GraphicsEnvironment ge = 
                GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        final URL url = getClass().getResource("fonts");
        final File dir = new File(url.toURI()); // here I get exception
        for (final File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, file));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new LFRuntimeException("A problem on font installing is occured!", e);
    }
}
```

When I run this code from file system, all works fine. But when I run it from jar I get following exception on file object creation:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical

So how can I read folder content from a jar?

P.S. I've already seen some similar questions, but the solution was for reading of files, and I need to read all files in a folder

Comment: Here's a way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12007322/1350762

Comment: @maba good Idea, but it uses third party classes. Another solutions?

Comment: Basically, you can't. One of the things I've done on the past, is had a known file/resource generated at build time, which lists all the resources within the specified location, then at runtime, I read this file and then can use getReaource to each individual resource it lists